# How do I compare two List<Map> types to identify the matching and non matching items

Tags: flutter, dart

What I want is to get all the matching and non matching items from two List types in dart.
So supposing I have a List a and List b, how do I obtain a difference say List c.

Below is a representation of my current problem.

```
 var a = [
{"id":"1","b":"2"},
{"id":"2","d":"4"},
{"id":"3","f":"6"}
]; 

 var b = [
{"id":"1","b":"2"},
{"id":"3","f":"6"}
];
```

How do I obtain a difference of List c :

```
c = [{"id":"2","d":"4"}]
```

Comment: You can check our package that we are using in our company. 
https://pub.dev/packages/fire_line_diff/example
It's port of NPM package https://www.npmjs.com/package/fire-line-diff. Hope it helps

Comment: @DavidSedlář okay thanks, checking it right now

Comment: Does your compare depend on only id filed or full  map?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh the full map

Comment: @DavidSedlář the package did not meet my needs, thanks

Comment: But for the last id:3 , it is just comparing with id.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh so far as I can get the difference , **c** , thus okay

Comment: then map will be compared with just id then?

Comment: Please, edit the question and provide more information about what you want to be compared.

Comment: @Wiktor  i have item edited the question

Comment: So you want to scan the two Lists of Map and find fields which exists only in either first or second List?

Comment: @Wiktor I want to do something like a subtraction, where i subtract a List of map ,**b** from another list of map **a**, to get a new list of map **c**.

Comment: Your problem statement is incomplete.  What happens with `{"id":"3","d":"6"}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can compare as below:

for non-matching record as:

```
  var c= a.where((e)=>b.where((ee)=>e['id']==ee['id']).toList().isEmpty).toList();
```

for matching record as:

```
 var c= a.where((e)=>b.where((ee)=>e['id']==ee['id']).toList().isNotEmpty).toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I've understood it well, but this would be my first approach. Time complexity isn't the best, it probably can be optimized. I may try to do it when I'll be sure it is what you're looking for.

```
typedef mapList = List<Map<String, String>>;

mapList substractMaps(mapList a, mapList b) {
  mapList difference = [];
  a.forEach((aMap){
    final currentIdValue = aMap['id'];
    bool found = false;
    b.forEach((bMap) {
      if(bMap['id'] == currentIdValue) {
        found = true;
      }
    });
    if(!found) {
      difference.add(aMap);
    }
  });
    
 return difference;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two lists of maps that you want to take the difference of.  The quickest solution is to turn the two lists into Sets of immutable Maps which can be properly used as Set keys, then take the Set difference.  Like this:

```
import 'package:fast_immutable_collections/fast_immutable_collections.dart';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  final a = [
    {"id": "1", "b": "2"},
    {"id": "2", "d": "4"},
    {"id": "3", "f": "6"}
  ];

  final b = [
    {"id": "1", "b": "2"},
    {"id": "3", "d": "6"}
  ];

  final aSet = a
      .map(
        (e) => IMap(e),
      )
      .toSet();
  final bSet = b
      .map(
        (e) => IMap(e),
      )
      .toSet();

  print(
    aSet.difference(bSet).toList(),
  );
}
```

This results in:

```
[{
   id: 2,
   d: 4
}, {
   id: 3,
   f: 6
}]
```

Which seems to be what you wanted.

Update: not quite.  You didn't specify what happens with `{"id":"3","d":"6"}`.  I include it as a difference of these sets.  You'll need to clarify your problem.